# Returning a ReadOnlyCollection from a method with an IList return type

Tags: c#, .net

Here I have the following bit of code:

```
    private IList<IState> _states = new List<IState>();
    private ReadOnlyCollection<IState> _statesViewer;

    public IList<IState> States { get { return _statesViewer; } }
```

I believe that generally it is preferable to return interfaces rather than the concrete classes themselves, but in this case, shouldn't I set as the return type of the `States` property a `ReadOnlyCollection`?

Any user of my library will think it is possible to anything you can do with an `IList` if I set it as so, and that means adding elements. That is not true and I'm definitely breaking the contract exposing it as an IList.

Am I right with this view or there is something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do whatever makes the API clearest. If the caller only needs to enumerate it you could expose as `IEnumerable<T>`, but I wouldn't be concerned about exposing it as `ReadOnlyCollection`. You could declare a custom type (interface or class) with just an indexer and enumerator, of course

Answer (score 3):

If it was me, I would simply expose it as

```
IEnumerable<IState>
```

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a good choice for any public property that represents a sequence.

It's the smallest contract possible that is still a sequence, which helps you stay decoupled.

It enables a rich collection of operations in Linq for objects, so you're offering your consumer a lot of power.

Answer (score 2):

For some cases i take the `IEnumerable<IState>` if people are only allowed to *run over the list*. But if i need some more built-in functionality for the outer world like index operator, Count, Contains, IndexOf, etc. i'll give them an `ReadOnlyCollection` as `IList` and write within the documentation that it is read only.